# LTC4362 protection circuit

Tags: current-source, current-limiting, over-voltage-protection

I found this IC that protects from Overcurrent, overvoltage and reverse polarity. I want to use it for 1A max so the datasheet's title "1.2A Overvoltage/overcurrent protector" convinced me to use it. My doubt arises when I scroll down to the typical application schematic:

[image]

Here the Vout is 5V but the Iout=0.5A. I've read the datasheet of the Si1471 and its Id=2.7A so it isn't limiting the possible Iout. My questions are: why does it display only 0.5A? and most importantly: can  the circuit shown output 1A?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LTC4362 is *specified* at 0.5A and can tolerate brief periods at 1.5A. Well, more if you disable the current sense like in figure 10. You need to check power dissipation for that.

The example could probably limited by the external pass MOSFET (the polarity protection), but at 120mohm should work fine.

It should definitely work fine at 1A, they simply give the specification at 500mA (probably their intended target)